# constructing shapes in a matrix - java

Tags: java, matrix

I'm having some troubles starting a programming assignment.
i have an matrix, size NXN with all zeros.

i need to create and check all of the "shapes" that can be drawn on this matrix.
a shape is a "line" of ones starting in the N,0 point - the line can first go either up or right ( if Mat[5][5] = 1, than the next 1 will be in [5][6] or in [4][5] ). from a cretin point called the decision point the line can only go right or down until it reaches the N row again and the line ends.

i need to go over ALL of the options for a line in a given matrix and perform some calculations (which is the easy part) and return the maximum from all of them.
my problem is that i don't know how i can receive all of the options. It should probably be some kind of recursion which at each point of the process gives me a matrix built from either picking down/up/right but im really stuck with it.

does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

[As you wanted a hint] use a [Backtracking Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).